# Jetpack Navigation Deep Link with wrong ActionBar button

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

When I open my application from the launcher icon, all the Navigation and ActionBar button works fine. But when I access the application from an explicit deep link, my ActionBar gets confused.

My main navigation is:

`-> [TaskListFragment] -> [TaskDetailFragment]`

When opening by the launcher icon, the back button shows correctly:
[image: Correct behavior]

In my app, you can create an alarm for each task, so when the alarm rings and the user clicks on the notification, the flow is:

`-> [TaskDetailFragment]`

Then, it shows the wrong button:
[image: Wrong behavior]
Clicking in the drawer icon, it returns to [TaskListFragment]. The behavior is correct, but the ActionBar icon is not.

This is how I'm creating the deep link:

```
NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
            .setDestination(R.id.taskDetailFragment)
            .setArguments(arguments)
            .createPendingIntent()
```

Here is the complete code on [GitHub](https://github.com/igorescodro/alkaa/tree/v1.3.1).

[MainActivity](https://github.com/igorescodro/alkaa/blob/v1.3.1/app/src/main/java/com/escodro/alkaa/ui/main/MainActivity.kt) with all the Navigation boilerplate.

And [my Navigation Graph](https://github.com/igorescodro/alkaa/blob/v1.3.1/app/src/main/res/navigation/nav_graph.xml).

I also tried several base implementation, such as Google's [Sunflower](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components) and Architecture Components Sample without success.

Comment: Is there a reason you're still using Navigation `1.0.0-beta01` and not the `1.0.0` stable release?

Comment: No, I need to update it. But even after updating it to androidx and using 2.0.0, the issue remains. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134627094) once I thought this was a bug in the library.

Actually the issue is that I'm using a `ActionBarDrawerToggle` to do a custom Drawer animation and based on the developer that replied to the issue:

> "[...] the Navigation documentation suggests not using ActionBarDrawerToggle at all, as transitions are handled for you"

And in the [Navigation docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer):

> Note: When using NavigationUI, the top app bar helpers automatically transition between the drawer icon and the Up icon as the current destination changes. You don't need to use ActionBarDrawerToggle.

Once I need the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` for the custom animation, I can't remove it. To fix the issue, I need to call my Drawer setup first with the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` definition and then call the Navigation setup methods, like `NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController()`.

---

**TL;DR**

If you are using `ActionBarDrawerToggle` with `Jetpack Navigation` make sure that you set the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` before call the `Navigation` methods.